# Can't write a char array in my kernel written in C

Tags: assembly, gcc, kernel, x86-64, osdev

I'm going to preface this by saying that I'm far from good at C or C++, but nonetheless I've decided to try and write my kernel in it... my problem lies with writting a string (char array), I can write a character but as soon as I give it an array of chars it doesn't work.

I've also done some testing and I found out that it apperently sees the char array length as being 0.

Here's my kernel...

```
#include "kernel.h"

void clear_screen(enum vga_color back, enum vga_color fore);
void print(char* msg, unsigned int line, enum vga_color back, enum vga_color fore);

int hex_combine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
int get_length(char* str);


void main(void)
{
    clear_screen(BLUE, WHITE);
    print("Unga Bunga", 0, BLUE, WHITE);
    for(;;);
};


void clear_screen(enum vga_color back, enum vga_color fore)
{
    unsigned char *vidmem = (unsigned char *) VGA_ADDR;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < (80*25*2))
    {
        vidmem[i] = ' ';
        vidmem[i+1] = hex_combine(back, fore);
        i+=2;
    };
};


void print(char* msg, unsigned int line, enum vga_color back, enum vga_color fore)
{
    unsigned char* vidmem = (unsigned char*) VGA_ADDR;
    unsigned int i = (line*80*2);

    for (char* chr = msg; *chr != '\0'; chr++)
    {
        vidmem[i]   = *chr;
        vidmem[i+1] = hex_combine(back, fore);

        chr++;
        i+=2;
    };
};


int hex_combine(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) { return (x<<4)|(y); }
int get_length(char* str)
{
    char* c;
    for (c = str; *c != '\0'; c++);
    return c - str;
}
```

And here's the header file for the kernel...

```
#ifndef KERNEL_H
#define KERNEL_H

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint32;

#define VGA_ADDR 0xB8000
#define BUFSIZE 2200

uint16* vga_buffer;

#define NULL 0

enum vga_color {
    BLACK,
    BLUE,
    GREEN,
    CYAN,
    RED,
    MAGENTA,
    BROWN,
    GREY,
    DARK_GREY,
    BRIGHT_BLUE,
    BRIGHT_GREEN,
    BRIGHT_CYAN,
    BRIGHT_RED,
    BRIGHT_MAGENTA,
    YELLOW,
    WHITE,
};

#endif
```

I don't know if you need it, but here's my bootloader...

```
[org 0x7C00]

KERNEL_ADDRESS equ 0x100000

cli
lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

; Switch to PM
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 0x1
mov cr0, eax

jmp 0x8:init_pm


[bits 32]

init_pm:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

call build_page_tables

; Enable PAE
mov eax, cr4
or eax, 1 << 5
mov cr4, eax

mov eax, cr4
or eax, 1 << 7
mov cr4, eax

mov eax, 0x1000
mov cr3, eax

; Set LME bit in EFER register
mov ecx, 0xC0000080     ; Operand of 'rdmsr' and 'wrmsr'
rdmsr                   ; Read before so we don't overwrite the content
or eax, 1 << 8          ; eax : operand of wrmsr
wrmsr

; Enable paging by setting CR0.PG bit to 1
mov eax, cr0
or eax, (1 << 31)
mov cr0, eax

; Load 64-bit GDT
lgdt [gdt64_descriptor]

; Jump to code segment in 64-bit GDT
jmp 0x8:init_lm


[bits 64]

init_lm:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov rbp, 0x90000
    mov rsp, rbp

    ; Load kernel from disk
    xor ebx, ebx    ; Upper 2 bytes above bh in ebx is for cylinder = 0x0
    mov bl, 0x2     ; Read from 2nd sector
    mov bh, 0x0     ; Head
    mov ch, 1       ; Read 1 sector
    mov rdi, KERNEL_ADDRESS
    call ata_chs_read

    
    jmp KERNEL_ADDRESS
    jmp $

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;[bits 16]
;; http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_%28BIOS%29

;load_loader:
    ;mov bx, LOADER_OFFSET  
    ;mov dh, 1          ; Load 1 sector (max allowed by BIOS is 128)
    ;mov dl, 0x80       ; Drive number

    ;mov ah, 0x02       ; Read function
    ;mov al, dh
    ;mov ch, 0x00       ; Cylinder
    ;mov dh, 0x00       ; Head
    ;; !! Sector is 1-based, and not 0-based
    ;mov cl, 0x02       ; 1st sector to read 
    ;int 0x13
    ;ret


[bits 32]
build_page_tables:
    ; PML4 starts at 0x1000
    mov eax, 0x2000     ; PDP base address
    or eax, 0b11        ; P and R/W bites
    mov ebx, 0x1000     ; MPL4 base address
    mov [ebx], eax

    mov eax, 0x3000     ; PD base address
    mov ebx, 0x2000     ; PDP physical address
    mov ecx, 64         ; 64 PDP

    build_PDP:
        or eax, 0b11
        mov [ebx], eax
        add ebx, 0x8
        add eax, 0x1000 ; Next PD page base address
        loop build_PDP

    mov eax, 0x0        ; 1st page physical base address
    mov ebx, 0x3000     ; PD physical base address
    mov ecx, 512

    build_PD:
        or eax, 0b10000011  ;P + R/W + PS (bit for 2MB page)
        mov [ebx], eax
        add ebx, 0x8
        add eax, 0x200000   ; Next 2MB physical page
        loop build_PD

    ;(tables end at 0x4000 => fits before Bios boot sector at 0x7c00)
    ret


;=============================================================================
; ATA read sectors (CHS mode) 
; Max head index is 15, giving 16 possible heads
; Max cylinder index can be a very large number (up to 65535)
; Sector is usually always 1-63, sector 0 reserved, max 255 sectors/track
; If using 63 sectors/track, max disk size = 31.5GB
; If using 255 sectors/track, max disk size = 127.5GB
; See OSDev forum links in bottom of [http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA]
;
; @param EBX The CHS values; 2 bytes, 1 byte (BH), 1 byte (BL) accordingly
; @param CH The number of sectors to read
; @param RDI The address of buffer to put data obtained from disk               
;
; @return None
;=============================================================================
[bits 64]
ata_chs_read:   pushfq
                push rax
                push rbx
                push rcx
                push rdx
                push rdi

                mov rdx, 0x1f6      ; Port to send drive & head numbers
                mov al, bh          ; Head index in BH
                and al, 00001111b   ; Head is only 4 bits long
                or  al, 10100000b   ; Default 1010b in high nibble
                out dx, al

                mov rdx, 0x1f2      ; Sector count port
                mov al, ch          ; Read CH sectors
                out dx, al

                mov rdx, 0x1f3      ; Sector number port
                mov al, bl          ; BL is sector index
                out dx, al

                mov rdx, 0x1f4      ; Cylinder low port
                mov eax, ebx        ; Byte 2 in ebx, just above BH
                mov cl, 16
                shr eax, cl         ; Shift down to AL
                out dx, al

                mov rdx, 0x1f5      ; Cylinder high port
                mov eax, ebx        ; Byte 3 in ebx, just above byte 2
                mov cl, 24
                shr eax, cl         ; Shift down to AL
                out dx, al

                mov rdx, 0x1f7      ; Command port
                mov al, 0x20        ; Read with retry
                out dx, al

.still_going:   in al, dx
                test al, 8          ; The sector buffer requires servicing
                jz .still_going     ; Until the sector buffer is ready

                mov rax, 512/2      ; To read 265 words = 1 sector
                xor bx, bx
                mov bl, ch          ; Read CH sectors
                mul bx
                mov rcx, rax        ; RCX is counter for INSW
                mov rdx, 0x1f0      ; Data port, in and out
                rep insw            ; In to [RDI]

                pop rdi
                pop rdx
                pop rcx
                pop rbx
                pop rax
                popfq
                ret

                
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[bits 16]

GDT:
; Null :
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

; Code :
    dw 0xffff       ; Limit
    dw 0x0          ; Base
    db 0x0          ; Base
    db 10011010b    ; 1st flag, Type flag
    db 11001111b    ; 2nd flag, Limit
    db 0x0          ; Base

; Data :
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_descriptor:
    dw $ - GDT - 1  ; 16-bit size
    dd GDT          ; 32-bit start address


[bits 32]
GDT64:
; Null :
    dq 0x0

; Code :
    dd 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0b10011000
    db 0b00100000
    db 0x0

; Data :
    dd 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0b10010000
    db 0b00000000
    db 0x0

gdt64_descriptor:
    dw $ - GDT64 - 1    ; 16-bit size
    dd GDT64            ; 32-bit start address

    
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[bits 16]
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I compile the whole thing using the bat file...

```
@echo off
wsl nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin -l dump/boot.list
wsl nasm -f elf64 loader.asm -o loader.o -l dump/loader.list

wsl cc -m64 -masm=intel -c kernel.c
wsl ld -Ttext 0x100000 -o kernel.elf loader.o kernel.o
wsl objcopy -R .note -R .comment -S -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin

wsl dd if=/dev/zero of=images/image.bin bs=512 count=2880
wsl dd if=boot.bin of=images/image.bin conv=notrunc
wsl dd if=kernel.bin of=images/image.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1

del boot.bin kernel.bin kernel.o loader.o kernel.elf

qemu-system-x86_64 images/image.bin
pause > nul
cls
```

Comment: Does your build system properly include the string? It may be placed in a separate section, such as `.rodata`. Verify it's in the image.

Comment: How would I go about verifiying it's in the image?

Comment: A hex editor or a dump tool such as `strings`.

Comment: So I've just did a hex dump, and I can see that the string `Unga Bunga` is in there

Comment: Is it in the same sector? You only seem to be reading one. Does the load address match the link address?

Comment: Okay so I've done some testing, and they appear to be in the same sector, I'm not quite sure how I check the two addresses

Comment: You could disassemble the whole program, look at where the string is, then look at where `main` is trying to get the string

Comment: It would help to know how you build your kernel, your bootloader and how you do the linking and the command used to build the disk image. Provide everything to reproduce your problem.

Comment: As well any linker script you use

Comment: I was able to get your code working here, which would make it helpful if you showed us the info I asked for. I was able to use your bootloader as is (at some point you wish to read more than 1 sector though). I was able to compile the kernel to a binary file that was less than 512 bytes (1 sector). The only obvious problem I saw is that `chr++;` in the `print` function needs to be removed since you already increment `chr` in the for loop. It printed `Unga Bunga` to the top left of the display and the screen background was blue and text was white.

Comment: There are a couple potential problems if booting on real hardware. The DS register may not be set to the value you expect. You need to ensure it is 0x0000 (because you use ORG 0x7c00) at the start before you use an instruction that references it (`lgdt [gdt_descriptor]`). I'd start with `xor ax, ax` `mov ds, ax` at the very start. Something your bootloader code doesn't do is enable the a20 line. Many emulators and VM may enable it by default but on real hardware and some environments that may not be the case.

Comment: Sorry I've been busy with work, I'll give the needed information now for future reference.

Comment: Can you show the *entire* `loader.asm` as well. I assume it calls `main` but I'd like to see the contents. I'd also like you to comment the line that deletes the intermediate files and tell me what size `kernel.bin` is and I'd be curious about the output of the command `objdump -x kernel.elf` . You should build the code using `-ffreestanding`

Comment: I'd compile the files with at least `-std=c99 -ffreestanding -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-red-zone -fno-pic` (you may wish to turn off SSE/FPU/AVX as well). The no unwind tables would eliminate the `.eh_frame` section. The code you have declares a variable in the for loop so probably want to at least specify C99. If compiling for size you may wish to use `-Os` (optimize for space), If you had a global variable in your code in the `.data` section you could end up with a very large file >2MiB because of default page size in 64-bit code and you'd be better off using a linker script.

Comment: If you did end up with a really big file because of the 2MiB page size you could add this to your linker (`ld`) options `-z max-page-size=1` . The only reason you'd want a size of 1 is to fit things in 512 bytes. Normally a page size is 4096 or 2MiB. And of course as I already mentioned there is a bug in `print`. Remove the `chr++;` that is just before `i+=2;` . I think something you should really consider is extending your ATA disk read function to read more than one sector. You will need it as your kernel starts growing. You might also consider LBA rather than CHS mode in the ATA read.

Comment: Replace is `-std=c99` with `-std=gnu99` if you intend to use GNU extensions or specify the minimum standard your code should compile with. This will keep some older GCC compilers happy. You may wish to add the `-Wextra -Wall` options to GCC compiling options to warn you of problems. It is often a good idea to fix or understand all the warnings as it can be helpful to catch some types of problems that could lead to unexpected behaviour when the code runs.

Comment: Adding ```-std=c99 -ffreestanding -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-red-zone -fno-pic``` worked like a charm thank you so muc... I did get a big file so I tried adding the ```-z max-page-size=1```... I've been reading up on the different cc options which made it a bit more clear why it didn't work before. Again thank you all so much.